# Как лучше организовать класс, который будет создавать URL линк

Tags: php

Я начинающий и еще не сталкивался с таким кодом, хочу все сделать красиво. Сразу же отмечу, что я не выбираю между этих способов, а просто привел их для того, чтобы точнее объяснить что именно мне нужно:

Есть несколько статичных линков которые я использую, используются они давольно часто, в разных частях кода. Иногда я хочу вызывать их в сокращенном виде (например, http://vk.cc/myLink), а иногда в длинном (mySite.ru/blaBla/Pay/send...)

Так же есть куча генерируемых ссылок. С ними вопросов нет.

С сокращением проблем нет, но я хочу иногда при создании объекта класса Link вызывать какие-то статичные ссылки. Можно сделать это вызывом функции, или использованием константы, но мне кажется такое решение задачи не лаконичным.

Вариант засунуть огромный линк при создании объекта я сразу отбрасываю. Не красиво, код превращается в какую-то страшную ужасть.

```
$link = new Link('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
$link->cutLink();

$user->sendMessage('Ты никогда не узнаешь как я это сделал, поэтому можно забить : $link');
```

Я могу каждый раз делать так:

```
$linkSOF = new Link();
$linkSOF->makeSOFAsk()->cutLing();
```

Этот вариант мне кажется не плохим, но не прельщает делать по отдельной функции для каждой заготовленной линки. Возможно так и стоит делать, не знаю. Но мне кажется что должен быть более приемлимый вариант.

Возможно стоить сделать констатну и передавать ее в конструктор при создании объекта?

```
const SHORT_SOFASK = 1;
cosnt LINK_SOFASK = 2;
```

В таком случае, если ни одна из констант не была передана, то можно задать линке значение нулл в конструкторе. И уже дальше уже вызывать фукнцию генерации линки.

Но в таком случае выйдет так, что в коде этих констатн может стать слишком много, да и перспектива прописывать их в каждом классе, где нужно вызвать ссылку мне не нравится.

Залезу потом через месяц такой в класс messageSender'a, увижу константы ссылок на личный кабинет, на пользовательское соглашение, на обучающие ролики ну ютуб и пойму, что все равно все переписывать нужно.

Поэтому вот, вопрос к вам, хорошим программистам, у которых есть такой опыт. Как это реализовать лаконично? В идеале - хотел бы ссылки на гит, где такое уже есть. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правило если у Вас есть ресурсы, которые используются постоянно в разных частях системы, то логичнее всего создать `config` файл, в котором будут лежать настройки сайта! Например json файл. Ну или другой удобный формат. И сделать следующее:

```
{
    "app": {
        "sitename": "Мой сайт",
        "baseurl": "https://ru.stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "links": {
        "firstlink": "какая-то ссылка для класса Link",
        "secondlink": "какая-то ссылка для класса Link"
    }
    ...
}
```

Далее Можно просто считывать классом Link данные из конфига после создания объекта, добавляя `baseurl` делая ссылки полными, или относительными! Или лучше создать вспомогательную функцию `config()` и сделать её глобальной (например через composer, если используете) в который будете передавать `config('links.firstlink')`, В данной функции разбиваете входной параметр через explode (по точке), считываете файл (json_decode($arr, true)) и просто `return $result["links"]["firstlink"]`. Ну это как пример! Тем самым в любом месте всегда можно получить статические данные для дальнейшего использования.
В вашем классе просто вызовите в конструкторе например private метод `getConfig()`. В результате код будет выглядеть хорошо и все длинные слова будут вынесены в отдельное место!!

Answer (score 1):

Как пример, будем использовать роутер.
Для этого создаем конфиг. Ключом будет любое простое выражение, которое будет вписываться в вашу структуру. Значением будет генерируемый относительный путь.

```
$config = [
'longlink1'=>'reallonglink/very/long/path',
'shortlink1'=>'shortlink'
]
```

Пример генерации ссылок:

```
$route->createUrl('longlink1', array('param_1'=>'some_value', 'param_2'=>'another_value'));
$route->createUrl('shortlink1');
```

Результатом будут сгенерированные ссылки

```
http://domain.ru/reallonglink/very/long/path/?param_1=some_value&param_2=another_value
http://domain.ru/shortlink/
```